# Reading file to arraylist with multiple data type

Tags: java, swing, types, text-files

I have a problem with reading from a text file to an arraylist. The problem is that i don't know how to read in multiple types, because in my arraylist there are Points, Strings, booleans, therefor linesplit doesn't work. I checked all the topics and didn't find a solution to this.

edit: Elrendezes class looks like

```
  class Elrendezes {
   protected Point Po;
   protected String hely;
   protected String foglalo;
   protected boolean foglalt;
  }
```

Here's how my file looks like:

```
 java.awt.Point[x=16,y=13], 1, name1, false
```

And the method to read is

```
public static ArrayList<Elrendezes> readDataFromFile(){
      ArrayList<Elrendezes> ElrList = new ArrayList<Elrendezes>();
      FileInputStream fstream = null;
      try
      {
          fstream = new FileInputStream("src/files/DataFile.txt");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
          String strLine = null ;
          String tokens[] = strLine.split(", ");


          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
           tokens = strLine.split(", ");
          // THIS DOES NOT WORK: ElrList.add(new Elrendezes(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]));
          }
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
          try { fstream.close(); } catch ( Exception ignore ) {}
      }
      return ElrList;

}
```

Comment: `THIS DOES NOT WORK` what doesn't work can please say a little bit about the error you are getting

Comment: How is the data file written? Did someone else wrote it? Do you have access to this code?

Comment: i make the file, and this is the error: constructor Elrendezes(String, String, String, String) is undefined, this is because the constructor of Elrendezes is Point, String, String, Boolean

Comment: So what is your problem? Parsing?

Comment: i might just make a point to string function, that'll probably help

Comment: rather you need a string to point function

Comment: yeah i meant to say that

Comment: Thanks for the help i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably dont know regular expressions, I will use:

1. Get `x` and `y`:

   ```
   int v1 = strLine.indexOf("x=");
   int v2 = strLine.indexOf(",y=");
   int v3 = strLine.indexOf("]")  ; 
   string x = strLine.substring(v1 +2, v2);
   string y = strLine.substring(v2 +3, v3);
   ```
2. Break point representation from the rest.

   ```
   string secondpart = strLine.substring(v3+1);
   ```
3. Now break `secondpart` with only the coma as separator.
4. Convert string representation, using [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and etc..
5. Construct your object back.

Note: written in a hurry, check if the indexes used for x, y and secondpart are correct.
I also assumed the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose a char to split the String.

Cast the split string into boolean, integer etc.

```
Elrendezes(String[] s){
Point Po = s[0]; // dont know how to cast string to point, never done before
hely = s[1];
foglalo = s[2];
foglalt = Boolean.parseBoolean(s[3]);
}
```